# Equivalent of Lauricella $F_D$ on an elliptic curve?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, elliptic-curves, hypergeometric-functions

Lauricella's hypergeometric function $F_D$ is related to (weighted)  configurations of points on $\mathbb{P}^1$. I am looking for generalizations to weighted point configurations on an elliptic curve. I can neither find references nor do I get very far in developing such a notion. I can write down an integral representation of a plausible candidate (in terms of products of powers of theta functions, a la  Schwarz-Christoffel) but fail to determine any further properties (such as a set of differential equations for example). Any references welcome!